# Is there any way to have a checkbox add a number "1" into a number type box upon clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Is there any way I can have a user check a box and it automatically adds a number 1 in a corresponding number box? This is what I have so far, but it's not adding a number into the box when I check it. Where am I going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".copyMe").keyup(function () {
        $(".copyMe").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<input class="copyMe" type="checkbox" />
<input class="copyMe" type="number" />
```

Comment: Both of your inputs have the same class, so `$(".copyMe").val(some value)` will set the value of both inputs. And you're setting the value to `$(this).val()`, but your checkbox doesn't have a value specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? ([Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4unjx41/))

```
<input class="copyMeCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<input class="copyMeNumber" type="number" />

$('.copyMeCheckbox').on('change',function(){
   $('.copyMeNumber').val(1);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was trying for! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Please mark my answer as correct if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have to differentiate between the check box and the number input. (EDIT: note that you can do this without changing the class, but I've done that here to be more specific in naming the elements). If you want to make the number input "1" when the box is checked, you have to have a handler on the checkbox. fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h42j0ph3/1/

```
<div class="checkbox-number-container">
   <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" />
   <input class="number-input" type="number" value="0" />
</div>

 $(".checkbox-number-container .check-box").on('click', function () {
     var $checkbox = $(this);
     var $numberInput = $checkbox.parent('.checkbox-number-container').find('.number-input');
     if($checkbox.is(':checked')){
        $numberInput.val(1);
     }
     else{
        $numberInput.val(0);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Its not necessary to keep 2 elements with seperate class to differentiate between them. By using selective operations, you can access each of them explicitly even with same class.

Comment: Thanks! I really needed the function of unselecting the box and having it go back to 0.

Comment: How would you go about doing this with multiple checkboxes without having all the number boxes getting a value added to them?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you love to keep your markup at it is, here's you can do to make it work :

```
<input class="copyMe" type="checkbox" />
<input class="copyMe" type="number" />


 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input:checkbox[class='copyMe']").on("change",function () 
        {
            $("input[type='number'][class='copyMe']").val('1');  
        });
    });
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s4unjx41/1/